# What does this SQL query replacing JSON text mean?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to understand a part of SQL query but I don't know what's it used for; can anyone help me?

I know it wants to replace something, but what is " *":"(.+)"*  ", and why the string like "store" can be used in substring()?

```
replace((
    CASE 
        WHEN(char_length(substring(xxx_json::text FROM 'Name":"(.+)" , "store')) > 0) 
        THEN substring(xxx_json::text FROM 'Name":"(.+)" , "store')
        ELSE substring(xxx_json::text FROM 'Name":"(.+)" , "employees') 
    END),'\u0016','''')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a variant of substring that does regular-expression matching.  The first argument, `xxx_json::text`, is the string to be searched.  The second argument is the regular expression to match.

Note that the second argument consists of the entire SQL string literal `'Name":"(.+)" , "store'` (in the first two cases).  Everything in that string, except for the `(.+)`, should literally match a portion of the string to be searched.  The `(.+)` is regex syntax.  A dot matches any character; a + means one or more occurrences; the parentheses define this as a capture group.  In this context, the text that matches the capture group is what will be returned by substring.

So for instance if the contents of the string to be searched was a simple JSON expression like this:  `{ "Name":"John Smith" , "store":"London" }`, the regular expression would match and the substring would return `'John Smith'`.

In short, this is a slightly hacky way of parsing JSON in SQL to extract the value of the Name element (or some element whose key ends with Name).

See section 9.7.3 in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-matching.html for detailed documentation on this form of substring.

Comment: thanks for your help and very detailed explanation. May I ask that is the role of "store" to help locate the position? No matter what the store content is London or New York, it always returns the John Smith? If a JSON expression like { "Name":"John Smith" , "location":"London" }, does it not return any value? Thank you.

Comment: Exactly.  Since the regular expression ends with "store", the value that comes afterwards doesn't matter to the match.  In fact, there could be nothing after "store", in which case it would not be a valid JSON string, but the regular expression would still match.